# Using IN clause in THEN portion of a CASE expression

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause

I want to include only certain customergroups for each region in my query. 
I am using the below query that shows an error.

```
select sum(salesvalue)
from sales 
where (case when Region = 'TN' then CustomerGroup in (68,75,78,69,51,77,66)
case when Region= 'KL' then CustomerGroup in (77,01,68,51,69,78) end)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without a `case` expression:

```
WHERE (Region = 'TN' AND CustomerGroup in (68,75,78,69,51,77,66))
OR    (Region= 'KL'  AND CustomerGroup in (77,01,68,51,69,78))
```

This produces a simple conditional, and it is arguably easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `CASE WHEN END` in `Where` clause.

Just use *AND/OR* logic like.

> `If the column = value And the column IN the list of values.`

```
select sum(salesvalue)
from sales 
where (Region = 'TN' AND CustomerGroup in (68,75,78,69,51,77,66))
       OR (Region= 'KL' AND CustomerGroup in (77,01,68,51,69,78))
```

Comment: @vicky Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help